# How does createrepo work. How does yum understand parse its files. A conceptual explanation

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I am **not** looking for a how-to on creating a repo (createrepo) or using yum.

I want to understand how they work together.
I want to know what files yum looks at and why, what those files contain.
I want to understand the structure of the repo and its files. I want to understand how it all works together.
I have read many how-to's, I am looking for a more conceptual understanding.

I working with Centos 6 32bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Createrepo creates some informational files that can be used by yum tool while fetching data from a reposiotry.
The files are filelists.xml,repomd.xml etc.
the below tutorial explains the complete yum working.
[How does YUM work?](http://www.slashroot.in/yum-repository-and-package-management-complete-tutorial)

Answer (score 3):

I can't provide a complete answer to the entire flow of `yum`, but the following page describes `createrepo` and the rpm-metadata provided by `createrepo`.

http://createrepo.baseurl.org/